# Shortcut for specifying modified files as arguments to git diff

Tags: git, diff

Given this result of `git status`:

```
modified: path/to/file-1.txt
modified: path/to/file-2.txt
```

Is there a shortcut equivalent of this?

```
git diff path/to/file-1.txt
```

Something like:

```
git diff {1}
```

So that I don't have to type the full path name.

I know `git stash` allows `git stash show stash@{1}`, so I believe there's something similar for `git diff`, but I haven't found it yet.

Thanks.

Comment: You can always use the middle-click paste to grab those filenames from git status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [git-number](https://github.com/holygeek/git-number), or [scm-breeze](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/scm_breeze).

Answer (score 1):

`git stash` operates on a stack whereas `git diff` does not. Hence the stack contents can be referred to, but not the other.